# npm run build giving Syntax Error on Ionic React when building react-native modules (react-native-stars)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I've been getting the following error:

```
> react-scripts build                                                   
> Creating an optimized production build...                             
> Failed to compile.                                                    
> ./node_modules/react-native-stars/index.js                            
> SyntaxError:
> /mnt/c/linux_share/ayelho-mockup/node_modules/react-native-stars/index.js:
> Unexpected token (35:8)                                               
> 33 |     return this.props.opacity ?                                  
> 34 |       this.isReactElement(this.props.fullStar) ?                 
> > 35 |         <View style={{opacity: partial}}>                                                                             
> >    |         ^
> 36 |           {this.props.fullStar}                                  
> 37 |         </View>                                                  
> 38 |         :
```

I've tried using react-native-star-rating and this gives a similar error (it fails on ). So it is probably something in my setup. Is there something I need to do to tell it that  is a tag?

The main app is written in typescript.